# NodeJs expressjs estructure

Tags: node.js, express

The idea is to develop a nodejs server for a web (js, css and html) and mobile app (with nativescript core).

The server will connect to MySQL, but the idea is make it reusable. I have to do many projects (any ones with MySQL, others with sql server, json database). I have the idea to develop a modular server, but I have not mucha idea about this.

I found examples with MVC pattern (a folder with alll views, another one for all controllers...) I think that could't be the best opcion in my case.

Are there any (easy to learn) documentation about doing it like components? All I found is min four yearls old. Is recomendable to use expressjs? Could be better to use MVC?

Comment: It truly depends on what you set out to achieve.  You need an analysis of your requirements to figure out exactly what use cases you are going to solve.  From this list you must then see which technology aligns between them all and figure out which tech is ideal e.g. starting from scratch or use frameworks that does a lot of heavy lifting.  This however comes at a price (price is that you must learn what the framework manages in order to work around them).  Typical frameworks allow expressjs middleware, so I would say that's a good start.

Comment: What's a "modular server"? How is it any different than boilerplate code that you can then develop app-specific logic on top of? In any case, requests for resources are generally OT for SO.

Comment: My idea of a modular server is, for example, to have a module that conects to my db  (that serves to all proyects with a similar structure), another one for authentication qhen the proyect needs it. for another db types, etc... For example I have a proyect A with login and  a proyect b without it. I can create a copy of my base server for the A with authentication and its db modules and another for proyect B deleting (or commenting) that modules.